# How to store only " in C# string

Tags: c#, json

I want to get JSON from string and I need to extract " instead of \" in my code.

Here is my code that I want to use it in:

```
internal static string ReturnRedditJsonPage(string subredditname)
{
    return 
    $"https://reddit.com/r/{subredditname}.json";
}
internal static Reddit ParseReddit(string subredditname)
{
    WebResponse response = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(ReturnRedditJsonPage(subredditname)).GetResponse();
    string responseContent = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd().Replace("\\",@"\").Replace("\"",((char)0x0022).ToString()).Trim();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Reddit>(responseContent);
}
internal static Uri[] GetMemesLinks(string subredditname)
{
    Reddit jsonData = ParseReddit(subredditname);
    List<Uri> result = new List<Uri>();
    foreach(Child child in jsonData.Data.Children)
    {
        result.Add(child.Data.Url);
    }
    return result.ToArray();
}
```

It gives me back JSON that I cannot parse because of \" in string instead of ". How can I fix it?

Comment: Please post the JSON data you are getting

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I'm finding it hard to understand the question - please could you show the *actual* JSON you're getting back? Also note that you should write it to a file or print it on the console or similar, rather than just looking in the debugger - otherwise you'll see an escaped form.

Comment: By using \" you just tell compiler that specific " doesn't end your string but is a part of it. And if you use Replace ("\"", "") you just remove " from your string not \". If you want to remove \" piece from your string you'd have to type Replace("\\\"", "")

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot parse"? Provide the JSON and the relevant error message. Note that `\"` is a *compile-time* escape sequence in string literals; they translate to `"`. Similarly, `\\` translates to `\`.

Comment: `Replace("\\",@"\")` Well, that is a rather pointless replace. And so is `Replace("\"",((char)0x0022).ToString())`. Because both Replace operations are replacing something with the same something; i.e. not changing anything...

Comment: I suggest to spend some time with a C# tutorial covering strings, string literals, and how (certain) characters are escaped in C# string literals. Your string.replace attempts kinda look like you don't understand / are unable to read string escape sequences...

Comment: Ok thx for all the answers I tried to get rid of this special characters. With first it worked but not with second. Problem with it was that /" wasn't translated to " by compilator. I'll probably stick with solution below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use [JSON.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) coupled with a little LINQ magic to extract all URI(s) out of the sub-reddit API.**

---

**Here's a demo, tweak to your requirements:**

```
internal static string ReturnRedditJsonURI(string SubRedditName)
{
    return $"https://reddit.com/r/{SubRedditName}.json";
}

// Does a HTTP GET request to the external Reddit API to get contents and de-serialize it
internal static async Task<JObject> ParseReddit(string SubRedditName)
{
       string exampleURI = ReturnRedditJsonURI(SubRedditName);

       JObject response = new JObject();
       using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
       {
            // Make the HTTP request now
            HttpResponseMessage msg = await client.GetAsync(exampleURI);

            // If HTTP 200 then go ahead and de-serialize
            if (msg.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {   
                string responseBody = await msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(responseBody);
            }
       }
       return response;
}

// Driver method to extract the URI(s) out of the reddit response
internal static async Task<List<Uri>> GetRedditURI(string SubRedditName)
{
    string subRedditName = "Metallica";
    JObject redditData = await ParseReddit(SubRedditName);

    List<Uri> redditURIList = new List<Uri>();

    try 
    {
        // TODO: instead of JObject use concrete POCO, but for now this seems to be it.

        redditURIList = redditData["data"]?["children"]?
            .Select(x => x["data"])
            .SelectMany(x => x)
            .Cast<JProperty>()
            .Where(x => x.Name == "url")
            .Select(x => x.Value.ToString())
            .Select(x => new Uri(x, UriKind.Absolute)).ToList() ?? new List<Uri>();

        return redditURIList;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return redditURIList;
    }
}
```